# Building GitHub pages locally using Nix

Tags: ruby, github-pages, zlib, nix, nixos

I'm on NixOS and I want to build locally some GitHub pages.

[GitHub seems to indicate](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/#step-3-optional-generate-jekyll-site-files) that I should create a `Gemfile` containing:

```
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
```

Following the [Nixpkgs manual section on Ruby](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-language-ruby), I did:

```
$ cat > Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
$ $(nix-build '<nixpkgs>' -A bundix --no-out-link)/bin/bundix --magic
```

which resulted in a build failure on Nokogiri:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The build failure is the following:

```
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
```

I've confirmed that the issue is when building Nokogiri by running:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.1'
```

in various environments (with `nix-shell -p zlib`, `nix-shell -p zlibStatic`, `nix-shell -p zlib libxml2`, `nix-shell -p zlib pkgconfig`, etc).

From searching on Google, it seems that Nokogiri is a very common dependency (e.g. Rails depends on it), so I guess most people have overcome the difficulty I'm confronted to.
What am I missing?

Comment: What's in your `gemset.nix`?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Is `gemset.nix` supposed to be created automatically by bundix? In that case, it didn't go far enough to create it.

Comment: Yes. I've gotten nokogiri to work, but I don't remember how I did it. I believe I followed this guide: https://blog.arkency.com/2016/04/packaging-ruby-programs-in-nixos/

Comment: Guess from my experience with other language, (I have zero knowledge on `ruby`),  having package in `nix-shell -p zlib` doesn't mean it will include as dependency automatically. If you are building via `stdenv.mkDerivation` you might need some thing similar to `buildInputs = [ zlib ];`

Comment: Tagging @zimbatm who seems to be a prominent member of the Ruby community of nixpkgs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short path**

If all you really need is to build a github page you just need to enter a shell with `nix-shell -p jekyll` and then `jekyll build` because now jekyll is packaged as an application

**Long path** to use when you wish to have jekyll and other gems in the same Gemfile

You can find detailed instructions here: [Building a Jekyll Environment with NixOS](https://stesie.github.io/2016/08/nixos-github-pages-env) (even though there is nothing specific to NixOS really)

I think that is an issue with the `--magic` flag (or that I didn't get the true usage of it) and that it doesn't use the special configuration some gems have in nixpkgs.

So to avoid that flag you can (full instructions in the [post above](https://stesie.github.io/2016/08/nixos-github-pages-env)):

1. create a bare Gemfile like you did, without the 'group' directive
2. in a shell with bundler call `bundler lock` to obtain the `Gemfile.lock`
3. call `bundix` with no arguments to obtain the `gemset.nix`
4. create a derivation that has in the `buildInputs` the `bundlerEnv` like explained in the manual.

   Bonus points for the `default.nix` of the blog because it starts jekyll local server as you type `nix-shell`

Comment: Excellent! You were spot on: it looks like the issue was indeed with the `--magic` flag.